# Resolving dependencies from parameters in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

Here are the interfaces and classes (for example):

```
public IReportGenerator
{
    string Build();
}

public interface IPersonReportGenerator : IReportGenerator

public class PersonReportGenerator : IPersonReportGenerator 
{
  private readonly int _personId;
  private readonly IPersonDb _personDb;

  public PersonReportGenerator(IPersonDb personDb, int personId)
  {
    _personDb = personDb;
    _personId = personId;
  }

  public string Build()
  {
    // get data with _personId;
    return "Person Report";
  }
}

public interface ICarReportGenerator : IReportGenerator

public class CarReportGenerator : ICarReportGenerator 
{
  private readonly guid _make;
  private readonly guid _model;
  private readonly ICarDb _cardDb;

  public CarReportGenerator (ICarDb cardDb, guid make, guid model)
  {
    _cardDb = cardDb;
    _make = make;
    _model = model;
  }

  public string Builder()
  {
    // get data with _make and _model;
    return "Car Report";
  }
}
```

Which are consumed by:

```
// MVC ActionResult to encapsulate the response for a report
public class ReportResult : ActionResult
{
  public ReportResult(IReportGenerator rg)
  {
  }
}
```

This is how I'm registering these:

```
containerBuilder cb;

cb.RegisterType<PersonReportGenerator >()
  .As<IPersonReportGenerator >();

cb.RegisterType<CarReportGenerator>()
  .As<ICarReportGenerator>();
```

Now in my action result.. and it's ugly:

```
public ActionResult GetReport(int personId)
{
  var report = 
    ((AutoFacDependencyResolver)DependencyResolver.Current)
    .ApplicationContainer.Resolve<PersonReportGenerator>(
      new NamedParameter("personId", personId)
    );

  return new ReportResult(report);
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to resolve this type of dependency using MVC/Autofac?

Comment: Why does the `ReportResult` class need the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change this interface:

```
public interface IPersonReportGenerator : IReportGenerator

public IReportGenerator
{
    string Build();
}
```

Then that creates a problem. By definition the interface defines how you interact with a class. The challenge is that you need to pass it a `personID`, but the interface doesn't allow it. So in effect the interface doesn't really define what the class needs to do.

If you aren't in a position to change that interface (something else already depends on it) then you can do what we do with legacy code - wrap it in the interface that we *do* need. It doesn't make the problem go away. It just creates an abstraction around it so that we don't have to continually deal with the problem.

```
public interface IPersonReportGeneratorV2 //Or some better name
{
    string GetReport(IPersonDb personDb, int personId);
}

public class LegacyPersonReportWrapper : IPersonReportGeneratorV2
{
    var generator = new PersonReportGenerator(personDb, personId);
    return generator.Build();
}
```

Now your controller can depend on `IPersonReportGeneratorV2`. There's still some ugliness, but now it's hidden away behind that new interface. Now you can register the wrapper as the implementation of the interface and let the container do its work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not know **personId** at design time, you do not want inject personId via constructor. *(There is away to do it in Autofac; it is ugly and complex.)*

There is a better and easier way of doing it.

```
public interface IReportGenerator
{
    string Build(ReportSetting setting);
}

public class ReportSetting
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public Guid CarMake { get; set; }
    public Guid CarModel { get; set; }
}

public class PersonReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
{
    private readonly IPersonDb _personDb;

    public PersonReportGenerator(IPersonDb personDb)
    {
        _personDb = personDb;
    }

    public string Build(ReportSetting setting)
    {
        // you can use setting.PersonId
    }
}

public class CarReportGenerator : IReportGenerator
{
    private readonly ICarDb _cardDb;
    public CarReportGenerator(ICarDb cardDb)
    {
        _cardDb = cardDb; 
    }

    public string Build(ReportSetting setting)
    {
        // you can use setting.CarMake and setting.CarModel
    }
}
```

### Autofac Registration

You can use [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html), and inject the desired dependency to controller based on the name.

For example,

```
cb.RegisterType<PersonReportGenerator>().Named<IReportGenerator>("PersonReport");
cb.RegisterType<CarReportGenerator>().Named<IReportGenerator>("CarReport");

cb.Register(c => new MyController(c.Resolve<IReportGenerator>("PersonReport")))
    .As<Controller>();
```

Comment: I suggested about as much - move the parameters from the constructor to the method call - but it was rejected on the basis that the interface must not be changed.

Comment: If IReportGenerator interface must not be changed, OP can create [Factory Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern) at runtime; it will totally changed the architecture except IReportGenerator.

Comment: That's close to what I recommended in the second answer. if the intent is to have a class that generates a report for a given `personId` then the exposed interface needs to reflect that. If it doesn't then the problems snowball from there. Looking at the original interface one would reasonably conclude that the report has no parameters. It makes an assumption that the implementation will take the parameters in the constructor. In other words, the interface doesn't indicate how to use its implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Don't resolve it in the `ActionResult`. Don't *explicitly* resolve it anywhere.

Declare it as a parameter in the constructor of your controller, like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IPersonReportGenerator _personReportGenerator;

    public MyController(IPersonReportGenerator personReportGenerator)
    {
        _personReportGenerator = personReportGenerator;
    }
}

public ActionResult GetReport(int personId)
{
    var report = _personReportGenerator.Builder();
    return new ReportResult(report);
}
```

(Assuming that "Builder" is the method that returns your report.)

If Autofac or any other DI container is set up to create your controllers then when it creates the controller to handle the request it will also resolve the dependencies for the controller, including `IPersonReportGenerator`.

The result is that your controller doesn't depend on a container or even know of it. It just depends on the interface it needs to depend on, and the container provides it.

If you haven't gotten as far as using the container as your controller factory [here's the documentation for Autofac](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html). The key is that *the container creates everything.* If the container creates the controller, then at the same time it can determine what it needs to pass to the constructor and create those classes also. (And if those classes also have dependencies it creates those too, and so on.) As long as the container creates the first object then it creates all of them (as long as the dependencies are registered, like you did with `IPersonReportGenerator` and `PersonReportGenerator`.)

Comment: I can't resolve it in the constructor of the controller because the personId is **required** for the object construction and isn't available until the `GetReport()` method is called...   (as I side note, the controllers are created by autofac).  Please review the question again.

Comment: Make the personId a parameter of GetReport(). It's not a dependency, is just a method argument.

Comment: Then it breaks the interface...  and then is no point in using an interface.  Each report has different requirements for parameters(either the constructor or the method).  (The `CarReportGenerator` doesn't need a `personId`)

Comment: Don't think of it as "breaking" the interface - think of it as making the interface the way it needs to be. You're *always* going to need to pass a personId to the report generator, but the interface doesn't indicate that. Right now the interface assumes that the class implementing it will figure out another way to get that id. But the logical way to pass it is as a method parameter.

Comment: Did you read my code?  *You're always going to need to pass a personId to the report generator* is simply not true, the CarReportGenerator **NEVER** needs a personid.

Comment: CarReportGenerator doesn't implement IPersonReportGenerator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109949/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-scott-hannen).

Comment: I'm not going to extend the discussion. *If* you write your report generator interfaces so that the specifics of the report are method parameters - a person Id where applicable, a car ID where applicable - you will see this design problem magically disappear and you'll be able to use the container as intended without having to call it directly from your controller. The dependencies for each class are configured at application startup. There's no way you're going to be able to configure these at startup so that they know which ids you want to generate reports for at runtime.

Comment: If i do that it breaks the interface `IReportGenerator`.  You don't understand the problem

Comment: If you absolutely cannot change that interface (which should change) then define a new interface that has person Id as a method parameter, and an implementation that wraps your legacy report generator, creates an instance, and passes the parameter to the constructor. What you have now is an interface for generating a report that a) requires an ID but b) there's no way to pass it that ID. That's the underlying problem.